# how to use variables in maps or associative array in java

Tags: java, ip, max, associative-array

**the problem:**
i have 3 integer value.

```
integer val1 = 23 ;  
integer val2 = 14 ;   
integer val3 = 6;
```

i need them to be associated with an IP. so i tried this.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("val1", "192.168.100.100");
map.put("val2", "192.168.100.101");
map.put("val3", "192.168.100.102");
```

but it seems it doesn't store integers in map. when i tried this in my code:

```
  System.out.println(map.get("val1"));
```

i got `null` as output.

**my code:**
my code is so long i can't paste here but i can explain some part of it. actually those 3 integers are random numbers so every time they are have different values.

```
  Random rand = new Random();
  int val1= rand.nextInt(101);
```

then i need to associate them with IPs. then find the max integer and use its IP in the rest of code:

```
  int maxnum = Math.max(val3, Math.max(val1, val2));

  map.get(maxnum);
```

how to solve the problem and achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your integers to be the `keys`, but you built a `Map` where key type is `String` : `Map<String, String>` and as you see you provide `"val1"` as key whch is `string`, different of `val1` the variable pointing here to an `Integer`

```
Integer val1 = 23 ;  
Integer val2 = 14 ;   
Integer val3 = 6;  

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(val1, "192.168.100.100");
map.put(val2, "192.168.100.101");
map.put(val3, "192.168.100.102"); 

System.out.println(map.get(val1)); // "192.168.100.100"
System.out.println(map.get(23));   // "192.168.100.100"
```